# Under what circumstances is an edit summary required?

Tags: support, editing

I was editing a [post](https://superuser.com/questions/390315/offline-update-avg) (now deleted, and I am sure that that has something to do with it) and it asked me for an edit summary of ten characters.

Under what circumstances would I need to provide such a summary on a post (not talking about a tag wiki here)?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a link to that topic? Did it still exist *after* the error message occurred?

Comment: @DanielBeck, I can't, the post was deleted. After I got that message, I put in a summary, but before I submit it, I got a message saying that the post had been deleted, and further edit would not be accepted.

Comment: Even if it's not accessible to you (yet), it's still around. Therefore the link. Maybe it's in your browsing history.

Comment: Edited to include link

Comment: For reference, a user _at least_ up to my rep level **always** has to give an edit summary of at least 10 characters

Comment: @Raystafarian, You only have to do that for suggested edits.

Comment: The only cases where I was forced to add a edit summary, in other sites, is when I don't have the privilege to edit every post; where I can edit any post, I am not asked for a edit summary, which is entered automatically from the system. This happens also on _Seasoned Advice_, where my reputation is 2751.